# Error getting the values of all fields of a data class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, reflection, data-class

I am trying to get all the field values of a data class using this extension function:

```
fun FinancialDataResponse.asDomainModel() = FinancialData(
    heading = this::class.memberProperties.map { it.name },
    data = this::class.memberProperties.map {it.get(this).toString()}
)
```

But I keep getting this error :

[image]

Can someone please tell me what will be the right way to get the values of all the fields for a data class in kotlin?

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the getter.call method instead. This will work:

```
fun FinancialDataResponse.asDomainModel() = FinancialData(
heading = this::class.memberProperties.map { it.name },
data = this::class.memberProperties.map { it.getter.call(this).toString() })
```